# GDI drawing small rect

Tags: c++, mfc, gdi

What happens if I draw rectangle, but before I set some World Transform such that size of rectangle becomes 0 and it will not be visible on screen?

Does GDI draw this 0 size rectangle anyway or there is some optimization?

My rect is definitly is not empty(for example CRect(0,0,10,10))but when I set world transform to DC(for example scaling with coeff 0.00001) when GDI draw it it becomes 0 size(0.00001*10 <1).

Comment: You can call `CRect::IsRectEmpty()` or `::IsRectEmpty(rect)` to test the rect. But 'yes' GDI probably does have many optimisations to avoid unnecessary drawing including empty rects.

Comment: @user1793036 problem is my rect is definitly is not empty(for example CRect(0,0,10,10))but when I set world transform to DC(for example scaling with coeff 0.00001) when GDI draw it it becomes 0 size(0.00001*10 <1).